# Getting LocalStack TCP connection error when trying to list AWS S3 buckets in Ruby tests

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, localstack

Im trying to list the AWS S3 Buckets but in doing so I'm getting the following **LocalStack** error message:

```
Failed to open TCP connection to docs-localstack:4566 (getaddrinfo: Temporary failure in name resolution) (Seahorse::Client::NetworkingError)
```

Here's is the code I have for **creating** a bucket, which seems to be working fine:-

awsbucket.rb file:

```
require 'aws-sdk-s3'

class AwsS3

  def aws_connect
    @s3 = Aws::S3::Client.new(
      access_key_id: 'test123',
      secret_access_key: 'test456',
      region: 'us-east-1',
      endpoint: 'http://docs-localstack:4566'
    )
  end

  def list_buckets
    response = @s3.list_buckets
    if response.buckets.count.zero?
      puts 'No buckets'
    else
      response.buckets.each do |bucket|
        puts "#{bucket.name}"
      end
    end
  end

  def create_bucket(name)
    response = @s3.create_bucket(bucket: name)
    if response.location == '/' + name
      return true
    else
      return false
    end
  rescue StandardError => e
    puts "Error creating bucket: #{e.message}"
    return false
  end
end#
```

I have an .rb file for the test step -

```
Given('I connect to AWS') do
  @client= AwsS3.new
  @client.aws_connect
end

Then('I create {string} bucket') do |name|
  @client.create_bucket(name)
end

Then('the list of buckets is shown') do
  @client.list_buckets
end
```

This is the code for the docker yml file -

```
version: "3.3" 

services: 
  localstack: 
    container_name: "${LOCALSTACK_DOCKER_NAME-localstack_main}" 
    image: localstack/localstack 
    network_mode: bridge 

    ports: 
      - "127.0.0.1:53:53"                # only required for Pro (DNS) 
      - "127.0.0.1:53:53/udp"            # only required for Pro (DNS) 
      - "127.0.0.1:443:443"              # only required for Pro (LocalStack HTTPS Edge Proxy)
      - "127.0.0.1:4510-4559:4510-4559"  # external service port range 
      - "127.0.0.1:4566:4566"            # LocalStack Edge Proxy 

    environment: 
      - DEBUG=${DEBUG-} 
      - DATA_DIR=${DATA_DIR-} 
      - LAMBDA_EXECUTOR=${LAMBDA_EXECUTOR-} 
      - LOCALSTACK_API_KEY=${LOCALSTACK_API_KEY-} 
      - HOST_TMP_FOLDER=${TMPDIR:-/tmp/}localstack 
      - DOCKER_HOST=unix:///var/run/docker.sock 

    volumes: 
      - "${TMPDIR:-/tmp}/localstack:/tmp/localstack" 
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"
```

So for creating a bucket it works fine, but when listing the buckets created I seem to get a TCP Connection issue.

This is the first time I'm using AWS S3 Buckets so apologies if the details are lacking, but not sure which area I'm messing up on.

Any ideas why I'm getting that error?

Comment: You should clarify that this is not actually Amazon S3. It's LocalStack, which includes an S3 emulator. Are you actually using LocalStack? Is it running?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with LocalStack. Is there a reason you're using `docs-localstack:4566` rather than `localstack:4566` or `localhost:4566`? Is there a local process actually listening on port 4566?

Comment: Noted. Yeah I have LocalStack running. I have a folder setup with the docker-compose.yml file which I run using the command line.

Comment: I don't think you need to include the host in the `ports` definition.  Removing the host may help.